# Different test objects pass individually but have error running together. [Does Python nosetests run different test classes in parallel?]

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have several test objects that I am connecting to DB in each of their setups. Apparently, my DB connection limits number of accesses per IP, since I am getting this error telling me that a connection is already established when I run all the tests/ folder, but if I run them separately, they all pass. So, I'm wondering if  it is the case that nosetests runs them in parallel? If so, is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Nose shouldn't run your tests in parallel by default; it should require you to explicitly pass in the `--processes` flag.  What else is going in your DB, How many connections does it have? How many does it support? Where are the connections coming from?

Comment: Thanks. Our DB is Impala, stored on HDFS. We are using ibis on Python to connect to it. When running nosetests -w tests/, I get this error that a conection from my IP is already established. I am using the format: "with impala.ibis_context() as context" so I assume after the with statement the connection should be closed

Answer (score 0):

We figured the problem out. It was not about nose running tests in parallel. It was one of tests changing an attribute of sys, which was not used in that particular test but was affecting others.